# React component not re-rendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react component that is designed to show a button whenever you are within a certain time limit of when something was created.

```
  var UndoButton = React.createClass({

  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return ({
      timeWindow: 900
    })
  },

  getInitialState: function() {
    return ({
      commentAge: this.props.timeWindow + 1
    })
  },

  determineDeletable: function() {
    this.setState({
      commentAge: this.commentAge()
    });
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.determineDeletable()
    this.timer = setInterval(this.determineDeletable, 1000);
  },

  componentWillUnMount: function() {
    clearTimer(this.timer);
  },

  commentAge: function() {
    return Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000) - this.props.created_at;
  },

  inPeriod: function() {
    return this.timeRemaining() > 0;
  },

  timeRemaining: function() {
    return this.props.timeWindow - this.state.commentAge;
  },

  render: function() {
    if (!this.inPeriod()) { return false }
    return (
      <a href='#' className='btn btn-xs btn-default'>Undo Comment ({this.timeRemaining()}s)</a>
    )
  }

});
```

Right now, this renders the button within the time window perfectly.  However, even though the state is updating every second, the render function does not appear to be running as the time remaining count does not change.  Also, when the time window is hit the button doesn't dissapear.

So, what's blocking this React component from rendering the correct information?

Comment: does your timeRemaining fn call only once right. So ?

Comment: Works for me. Here's a [bin](http://www.webpackbin.com/EyWkHSvPW). It calls `render()` as fine but doesn't show anything as your `this.inPeriod()`evaluates as `false`.

Comment: wel, obv you need the props.  You can remove the InPeriod check for the purposes of this

Comment: It works fine for me as is, if I pass a `created_at` prop value. (i.e. `created_at={new Date().getTime() / 1000}`).  Just a thought... you're using a different naming convention for that prop name, everything else you're using camelcase. Maybe double check that you're using the correct name when passing it in?

Comment: Are you seeing the on the button update every second though?